# vb6 / open url in same browser tab via api or something else?

Tags: vb6

Wondering if someone could help me with the following? I'd like to:
a) Find the current open browser window
b) Navigate to a webpage WITHIN the same tab (not open a new window)

I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for, if I use shellexecute, I can open a browser window - but, if already opened - it opens a "new" tab with the URL, instead of replacing the existing URL.

How can I replace it? I was thinking of using something like EnumProc to find the existing browser window - but then - I don't know what I need to do to change the url once I find the window handle? (Would it be something to do with sendkeys? Or - is there something I can use specifically to change the current browser window? Or would that depend on browser (i.e., chrome vs MSIE vs firefox).

Most important though - is navigating to different pages within the *same* tab as opposed to constnatly opening new instances.

Thanks very much!

Comment: There are lots of browsers out there.  I imagine each one would have a different method to enumerate its control.  Have you thought of using SendKeys to control it?

Comment: yes - but (a) its been a while since I did actual API coding, so don't remember how to find the instance of a browser. (b) same with sendkeys.

Comment: if I was just focusing on MSIE - how would I do that?

Comment: SendKeys is not an API.  It's part of [VB6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement).

Comment: ok. well - do you know of a solution?

Comment: I think @AngryHacker 's point is to send keystroke to IE from VB6 as though it were a human user telling it what to do. Try it and edit some more details about what you did into your question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> if I was just focusing on MSIE - how would I do that?

Windows exposes a Shell Windows collection via COM that includes Explorer & IE windows - in the latter case you will get one windows per tab so:

```
Dim shApp: Set shApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim shWnd: Set shWnd = shApp.Windows()

Dim i As Variant, ie As Object

For i = 0 To shWnd.Count - 1

    If shWnd.Item(i).Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        '// got an IE tab
        Set ie = shWnd.Item(i)

        '// is it the tab we want - based on url
        If (LCase$(ie.LocationUrl) = "https://stackoverflow.com/") Then
            '// if so send it somewhere else
            ie.Navigate2 "http://reddit.com"
        End If
    End If

Next
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Tried this - doesn't seem to work. (Maybe it does with previous versions of windows?) I am using Windows 10/microsoft edge... strangeley - there does seem to be an instance of MSIE (not edge) running in the process list - but running this first of all only finds the fileexplorer & MSIE windows (so 3) - but if I try navigating, nothing happens (edge doesn't do anything). any suggestions? thanks!